# How Do I Create Tests for External Links using Rspec and Capybara?

Tags: rspec, capybara, rspec2, rspec-rails

I have a Ruby on Rails 3.2.6 application where I have written tests for links within the application using code like below:

```
visit about_path
click_link "Frequently Asked Questions (FAQ)"
page.should have_selector 'title', text: full_title('Frequently Asked Questions (FAQ)')
```

I have links throughout the application where people can follow us on Twitter and Facebook.  When they click on these links they open in a new window.  I would like to verify that when they click the links that they are going to the proper page.

I have purchased The Rspec Book from Amazon since I am still learning about test driven development, Rspec and Capybara.  I have checked several sections of the book but could not find any information addressing this issue.

[http://www.amazon.com/The-RSpec-Book-Behaviour-Development/dp/1934356379](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356379)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check your own code (that generated page contains right links) - then test the `href` property of the link in question. Something like that:

```
href = "http://www.amazon.com/The-RSpec-Book-Behaviour-Development/dp/1934356379"
page.should have_selector "a[href='#{href}']", text: "The Rspec Book"
```

If you want to check urls themselves (that you copied it right or that url still points to the right page) - then here it is relevant Capybara docs: [Calling remote servers](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#calling-remote-servers).

Comment: just attempted to do this with href = "facebook.com/iktusnetecosystem"; page.should have_selector "a[href='#{href}']", text: "Follow us on Facebook" I also tried doing this without using the variable. I got the following error both times: Failure/Error: click_link "Facebook" ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches [GET] "/iktusnetecosystem" The code works fine. I just want to check my code, not Facebook.  It looks like it is expecting a route to be defined on config/routes.db which to me makes no sense.

Comment: This error is not related to the rspec code snippet we are discussing. You get it when Rails tries to render the page. I don't see your code so it's impossible to say what's wrong. My guess is you are using Rails link_to helpers and they are for internal links.

Comment: I have decided to not do the tests for the external links since there is a slim chance they will change.  I felt that what I was doing would only work for internal links.  You confirmed my suspicions.  Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Capybara uses the :rack_test driver, which is fast but limited: it does not support JavaScript, nor is it able to access HTTP resources outside of your Rack application, such as remote APIs and OAuth services. To get around these limitations, you can set up a different default driver for your features. For example if you'd prefer to run everything in Selenium, you could do:

> Capybara.default_driver = :selenium

https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara